# react I want to get the params of the react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react and react-router-dom.
I want to get the value of :groupId in the User component.
In the Groups component, I can use useParams to get the groupId, but I want to get the groupId in the User component and pass it to the Groups component as a props.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, useHistory, useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
import User from 'components/User';
import useSearchParams from './useSearchParams';

export const User = () => {
  const {query, setQuery} = useSearchParams();
  const history = useHistory();
  const {userId} = useParams<{
    userId: string;
  }>();

  return (
    <div>
      <Route path="/users/:userId/groups/:groupId">
        <Groups
          onClose={() =>
            history.push(`/users/${userId}/groups${location.search}`)
          }
        />
      </Route>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
import React from 'react';

interface Props {
  groupId?: string;
  onClose: () => void;
}

export const Groups = ({groupId, onClose}: Props) => {
  const params = useParams<{prospectId: string}>();
  console.log(params)
   
  return (
    <div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Why do you want, or need, to get the route params in `User` when `User` is the component rendering the route defining them? Why *not* just use the `useParams` hook in `Group`, that's how it's all designed to work. Can you perhaps explain the use case?

Answer (score 0):

you can get groupId by split pathName and get the last item

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, useHistory, useParams,useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';
import User from 'components/User';
import useSearchParams from './useSearchParams';

export const User = () => {
  const {query, setQuery} = useSearchParams();
  const history = useHistory();
  const {userId} = useParams<{
    userId: string;
  }>();
 const location = useLocation();
 const groupId = location.pathname.split("/").pop();

  return (
    <div>
      <Route path="/users/:userId/groups/:groupId">
        <Groups groupId ={groupId }
          onClose={() =>
            history.push(`/users/${userId}/groups${location.search}`)
          }
        />
      </Route>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: There is nothing in location.search.
''is.

Comment: you can split pathName and get GroupId then you can pass it as props

Comment: When I get location.pathname, I get this data: I want to get a5667fbb-eaaa4-42bb-8bbb.
If I use pop(), I get the timeline.

Comment: ['', ‘users', 'dnsidsiaji-3sse2-4ss13', 'groups', 'a5667fbb-eaaa4-42bb-8bbb', 'timeline']

Comment: you must add the exact path otherwise you only get a timeline as groupId

Comment: <Route exact path="/users/:userId/groups/:groupId">
        <Groups groupId={groupId} />
      </Route>
      <Redirect to="/users/:userId/groups/:groupId" />

Answer (score 0):

You can even pass ids as a state in `history.push(location, state)`
and update the groups component to get the group ids from the state instead of passing group ids as part of the URL.

Edit:
To pass state:

```
    history.push({ 
     pathname: <your_path>,
     state: <state or props>
    })
```

To retrieve state use:

```
    const location = useLocation()
    const state = location.state
```

Comment: How do I implement this?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).